# Custom sort of a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, sorting, data-structures

I only started learning Python few days ago, and I wanted to implement my little project in it. I need to sort a list of `(string, integer)` in a descending order by the number value, but alphabetically if the number is the same for more than one tuple. So I have a list, say:

```
tuples = [('ggg', 5), ('aaa', 5), ('bbb', 6), ('zzz', 6)]
tuples.sort(key=lambda score: score[1], reverse=True)
```

This returns:

```
[('bbb', 6), ('zzz', 6), ('ggg', 5), ('aaa', 5)]
```

But what I want to get is:

```
[('bbb', 6), ('zzz', 6), ('aaa', 5), ('ggg', 5)]
```

In Java I just implemented a comparator for a custom tuple:

```
class Pair {
    public final String s;
    public final Integer i;

    public Pair(String s, Integer i) {
        this.s = s;
        this.i = i;
    }
}

class PairComparator implements Comparator<Pair> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Pair p1, Pair p2) {
        int c = p1.i.compareTo(p2.i);
        return (c == 0) ? p1.s.compareTo(p2.s) : c * (-1);
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to go about doing that in a `lambda` expression in Python.

Comment: So you want descending on the number & then ascending on the letters?

Comment: FWIW, Python 2 allows a custom comparison function argument for `sort` (and `max` & `min`), but that's been phased out in Python 3, since it's less efficient: a custom key function only needs to be called once for each key, but a custom comparison function gets called on _every_ comparison.

Comment: It _is_ possible to implement custom comparison in Python 3: create a class that implements the [rich comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) methods. OTOH, Python's built-in `sort` (aka Timsort) is stable, so it may be adequate to just sort the list multiple times with different keys, rather than using a custom comparison when you have a complex sorting requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way would be have `key` return a tuple and multiply the score by -1. For example:

```
>>> tuples.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
>>> tuples
[('bbb', 6), ('zzz', 6), ('aaa', 5), ('ggg', 5)]
```

This will sort the integers in descending order and then the strings in ascending order.

Comment: I should've known I'd get ninja'd if I posted a comment. :)

Comment: It's happened to me more times than I can count :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can just sort based on negative shape of the number and don't use the `reverse=True` :

```
>>> >>> tuples.sort(key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0]))
>>> tuples
[('bbb', 6), ('zzz', 6), ('aaa', 5), ('ggg', 5)]
```

Comment: If you don't specify `x[0]` in the key _it will be ignored_ and since Timsort is stable, the ordering of items based on `x[0]` won't change. Try your code on `[('bbb', 6), ('zzz', 6), ('aaa', 5), ('xxx', 5), ('ggg', 5)]`.

Comment: @PM2Ring oh yeah I missed the `lambda`, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to sort them twice using operator module function [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). We first sort by the first element in ascending order and then sort by the second element in descending order(though this is less efficient).

```
In [1]: from operator import itemgetter

In [2]: tuples = [('ggg', 5), ('aaa', 5), ('bbb', 6), ('zzz', 6)]

In [3]: tuples.sort(key=itemgetter(0)) # [('aaa', 5), ('bbb', 6), ('ggg', 5), ('zzz', 6)]

In [4]: tuples.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True) # sort by 2nd element in descending order

In [5]: tuples
Out[5]: [('bbb', 6), ('zzz', 6), ('aaa', 5), ('ggg', 5)]
```